# ASP.NET MVC 4 - User roles and User Profile Management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a simple MVC 4 application which has two types of members Admin and Registered. Admin can add, edit, delete members as well as add, delete, edit events. Registered members can edit their profile and view the events.

I am new to ASP.NET, I am trying to get an idea where to start. What is the best way to approach an application like this.

The main questions
- What is the best way to achieve user roles and user management
- How to restrict users from accessing pages they are not authorised to access

I just want to be pointed in the right direction, I have looked around but didn't find anything useful. Just hopping someone will guide me based on experience with ASP.Net

Comment: This a rather broad question, there are many solution you could pursue. Google is your best friend, that and I'll always recommend reading books on the subject. So for you starting out. Google the subject, do some research and if you have a more specific issue you're having than you can open a question at that point.

Comment: Consider ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I did come across ASp.NET Identity which I was researching and also something called Areas, So what I understand is that Identity lets you create user roles and then you add an attribute to the code which you want the user to be able to use, where as in Areas the code is completely separated from other Areas. I think Identity in the way to go, I will look more into it. Also does identity allow the Admin to edit members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently ASP.NET encourages to use Claim based identity. With claims you stop thinking in terms of user roles, and start thinking in permissions or claims.

Then You'll have teo different users, users with permissions (claims) to edit users and events, and users with permissions only to see their info and view events only.

[This tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx) can guide you in your path to build the project.

Comment: is this the same as ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET Identity is the new authentication mechanism in .NET, is called claim-aware authentication too.